# while deleting data in particular range deleting all data from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Transaction_tbl` with these columns:

```
transactid   Tbarcode     dtime

1            100          2013-04-16 14:15:47.243
2            101          2013-05-10 10:15:47.243
3            102          2014-02-20 02:15:48.000
```

In this table, `transactid` is the primary key.

I have one more table `KHanger_tbl` with these columns:

```
transactid   Hbarcode
1             21
2             22
3             23
```

in my `KHanger_tbl` this `transactid is the foregin key`

I want to move date range <=2013-12-30 data from `Transaction` table to another table called `Transaction2013..`  (i mean data in the 2013)

so i wrote query like this:

First query

```
SELECT * 
INTO   transaction2013 
FROM   transaction_tbl 
WHERE  dtime <= '2013-12-30'
```

Second Query

```
    SELECT k.transactid, 
       k.tid, 
       k.requested, 
       k.hbarcode, 
       k.reqloc, 
       k.delivered 
INTO   khanger2013 
FROM   khanger_tbl k 
       INNER JOIN transaction_tbl t 
               ON t.transactid = k.transactid 
WHERE  t.dtime <= '2013-12-30'
```

then i want to delete corresponding 2013 data from Khanger_tbl and Transaction_tbl so first i wrote query like this:

```
    DELETE FROM khanger_tbl 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   khanger_tbl 
                      INNER JOIN transaction_tbl 
                              ON transaction_tbl.transactid = 
                                 khanger_tbl.transactid 
                                 AND transaction_tbl.dtime <= '2013-12-30');
```

but this is deleted my entire KHanger_tbl ..what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DELETE query deletes all rows because you don't have relation with inner subquery so for each row from `KHandler_tbl` subquery exists. Try to use the following:

```
DELETE T1
FROM KHanger_tbl T1
INNER JOIN Transaction_tbl T2
  ON T1.transactid = T2.transactid
Where T2.dtime <='2013-12-30'
```

Or just

```
  DELETE FROM KHanger_tbl 
        WHERE transactid IN (SELECT transactid 
                              FROM Transaction_tbl 
                              WHERE dtime <='2013-12-30')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Oracle syntax to delete records in SQL Server.  SQL Server allows you do this:

```
DELETE FROM khanger_tbl a
INNER JOIN transaction_tbl b on a.transactid = b.transactid
WHERE b.dtime <= '2013-12-30';
```

Hope that helps.